# Access subdomain directly from IP Address

Tags: linux, apache, google-chrome, dns, ip

I have server located under X.Y.Z.C IP address. It runs Apache2. I've added additional domain to it, let us call it A. When I want to add something to it, I have to send files to A subdirectory in public_html. However I want to test my website, before I change DNSes to my server. My question is: how can I access files of domain A? I tried to visit http://X.Y.Z.C/A/ but met "404" error. How can I access folder of my domain directly from IP address? (If that has any matter, I have access to shell)

*Of course IP is different than X.Y.Z.C and domain isn't "A".*

Comment: so you have one site for both domains?

Comment: I have one server for four domains

Comment: Each one has own folder in `public_html`

Comment: But you are not using virtual hosts?